# Android: Progress dialog not shown at 1st time (using Thread or AsyncTask for longDuration operation)

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have problem in my app with progress dialog in AsyncTask: 
my `AsyncTask` is doing some geting data from internet in `doInBackGround()`, I am starting progress dialog in `onPreExecute()`, finish dialog in  `onPostExecute()`.

I execute this asyncTask when click on Button. 1st time When I click this button (long operation takes place) progress dialog is not shown. But next times Progress dialog is shown normaly.

What can be the problem that 1st time of running `AsyncTask`, progress dialog isnt shown ?

this is onClick method:

```
public void onClickFind(View view){
 new Task_Search().execute();
}
```

This is task `Task_Search`:

```
private class Task_Search extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 protected void onPreExecute() {
  showDialog(DIALOG_TASKING);
 }

 protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
  //some geting of web content here
 }

 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
 protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
  dismissDialog(DIALOG_TASKING);
 }
}
```

progress dialog defined in `MainActivity`:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
 switch (id) {
 case DIALOG_TASKING:
  mSearchDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
  mSearchDialog.setMessage("Searching for field number..");
  mSearchDialog.setCancelable(true);
  return mSearchDialog;
  }
 return super.onCreateDialog(id);
}
```

Before of using `AsyncTask` I used separate Thread for downloading data instead: in `onClick`, I started first `progressDialog` then Thread, when Thread finished also `progressDialog` was stoped, 
Behaviour was same:
1st time of click on Button dialog wasnt shown, next times its shown.

Anybody who can help ?

Answer (score 0):

I cant see you calling show() on the dialog.

Replace

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected void onPreExecute() {
    showDialog(DIALOG_TASKING);
}
```

with

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
protected void onPreExecute() {
    showDialog(DIALOG_TASKING).show();
}
```

Comment: Yep I mistook it for the user-defined method. I recommend not using showDialog in any case but create my own ProgressDialog and show it.

Comment: I agree, i recommend it too!

Comment: I replaced it, and behaiour is same.

Answer (score 0):

Do not call showDialog insode onPreExecute(). 
AsyncTask provides publishProgress() method which can be invoked from doInBackground() to publish updates on the UI thread.

Comment: `onPreExecute()` runs on the UI thread also, and is provided for this reason, among others.

Comment: i never said it does not run on the UI thread. It is obvious he wants to show progress done by doInBackground() inside the dialog box. onPreExecute runs before doInBackground, so how can he can showDialog there.
Please do not downvote before understanding the problem and the answer

Comment: Showing the ProgressDialog in onPreExecute doesn't need any information from doInBackground. Updating the progress itself does, but that has nothing to do with it showing. Most AsyncTask/ProgressDialog examples do it this way, and even Google recommends it. Read [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html),  under **The 4 Steps**.

Comment: Oh, my bad.
@Geobits is right if you just want to show the dialog from onPreExecute.
I wonder if it has to do something with the '@override' notation.

Comment: AsyncTask is used exactly for these purposes. So your answer is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Okay,
I created in MainActivity my own methods:

```
public void showProgressDialog() {
 if (mProgressDialog == null) {
  mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
  mProgressDialog.setMessage("Searching for field number..");
  mProgressDialog.show();
  return;
 }else{
  mProgressDialog.setMessage("Searching for field number..");
  mProgressDialog.show();
  return;
 }
```

}

also:

```
public void closeProgressDialog() {
 if (mProgressDialog != null) {
  mProgressDialog.dismiss();
 }
 return;
}
```

I changed AsyncTask following:

```
private class Task_Search extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
 protected void onPreExecute() {
  // showDialog(DIALOG_TASKING);
  showProgressDialog();
 }

 protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
 //Some long duration stuff here
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
  //dismissDialog(DIALOG_TASKING);
  closeProgressDialog();
 }
}
```

`mProgressDialog` is a private member of MainActivity

```
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
```

Situation is same: wheck onClick on button: 1st time ProgressDialog stuck, next times it works perfect

Comment: What do you mean by stuck? Does it not show indeterminate spinning?

Comment: It does not show at first usage of operation (when click on button operation takes place + spinning progress dialog should occurs), it shows next times..

Comment: I still havent found out what could be the problem, I tested it also on real HW, HTC Sensation, and Samsung Galaxy Pad 2 and its same like in AVD